# Как преобразовать XML to Java?

Tags: java, xml

На сервер приходит xml-файл:

```
<property name="some name">
    <property name="some name"></property>
    <property name="some name"></property>
    <property name="some name"></property>
    <property name="some name"></property>
</property>
<property name="some name"></property>
<property name="some name"></property>
<property name="some name"></property>
<property name="some name"></property>
<property name="some name"></property>
<property name="some name"></property>
```

Как в этом случае должен выглядеть java-объект? И насколько корректен XML?

Comment: И что вы хотите чтобы вам ответили? Тот кусок xml который вы показали, точнее КАК его показали, говорит чуть менее чем ни о чем

Comment: Да, приведите какой-нибудь пример. Если в Java, то XML можно распарсить, создав модель и затем распкаовать

Answer (score 0):

1. Объект или класс java должен содержать все свойства указанные в xml схеме.
2. Объект может содержать только часть данных , которые приходят в xml документе. И тогда необходимо его парсить, вытягивать данные и присваивать соответствующим полям вашего класса.
3. Ваш пример и вопрос очень не содержательны.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Это тестовое задание для устройства на работу и в нём описано, что этот xml файл будет приходить на сервер. Видимо, придется немного пофантазировать с полями и значениями....

Comment: Вам надо разобраться что такое ХML, JAXB, парсеры.....и тогда эти вопросы отпадут сами собой.

Comment: Уже разбираюсь)